# Reload data on fnDraw() function

Tags: jquery, datatables

Getting data from server side and then adding the data to Datatables. but on calling `fndraw()` function. The ajax is not loaded again and the oSettings_aData is blank.

calling  `$("#clientTable").dataTable().fnDraw();` but no data is loaded in the table on click of a button.

Here is my function to fill datatable.

```js
function fillGrid() {
  alert("enterened fillgrid");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'BehindCode/client.aspx/fillgrid',

    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function() {



      $('#gridLoadingDiv').attr('style', 'display:block');
    },
    complete: function() {


      $('#gridLoadingDiv').attr('style', 'display:none');
    },
    data: "{}",

    success: function(data) {
      //data = data.d;
      data = JSON.parse(data.d).Data;
      //  alert(data);

      alert("entered success");

      $("#clientTable").DataTable({

        "stateSave": true,
        "searching": true,
        "processing": true,
        "data": data,
        // "ordering": false,
        "order": [
          [2, "asc"]
        ],

        "columns": [{
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ' <input type="checkbox" onclick="return selectOne();" />',
            "sorting": false
          },
          {
            "data": "CLIENT_ID",
            "visible": false
          },
          {
            "data": "CLIENT_NAME"
          },

          {
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ' <a ><img id="editimg" src="images/edit.png" width="15px" alt="edit" onclick="callEdit(this);" /></a>',
            "sorting": false
          }
        ],

        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
          alert(oSettings);
          alert("draw called");

        }
      });






    }
  });


}
```

Comment: i done something similar on button click but i used `sAjaxSource` with combination of `fnServerData` . in `fnServerData` i had a ajax call in success i do clear table and will call `fnDraw()` which works cool .

Comment: please post your code. sAjaxSource file too

Comment: may be you can look into `table.api().ajax.reload();` which will work if you using latest DT version

Comment: Did you try new method `$().DataTable().ajax()`? It works well with such situation..  http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax

Comment: @supercool you beat me to this :P

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a basic of my code which i hope can be helpful .

**My DataTable:**

```
 var ETable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({

       //bProcessing,bWidth etc comes above 
        "sAjaxSource": "../Employee/AjaxHandler",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

        //Inside i have ajax call under click function like this 

                                      $.ajax({
           //on click i am deleting a row on success i am reloading table 
                                            "success": function (data) {
                                                ETable.fnClearTable(0);
                                                ETable.fnDraw();
                                            }
                                        });
```

**My on load Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({

//under success i call fnCallback(data)

});
```

Trick here is when you call fnDraw after clearing  a table the `ajax call on load` will fire and give you latest and fill the table via `fnCallback` .